# How to get value of textbox in selenium webdriver , Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-chromedriver

I'm struggling to get the actual text of the text box as I need it as a text to store it in a variable rather than comparing it against a value, because I need to add it to the end of the url to call another page.

I tried using the code suggested by ebeal but it didn't do what I want:

```
var access_token = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("AccToken"))
                         .getAttribute("value")
                         .then(console.log);

// This outputs the right result but only to the console as I can't save it to a variable

var access_token = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("AccToken")) 
                         .getText();

access_token = access_token.then(function(value){
                                   console.log(value);
                                });

console.log("the new one : " + access_token); 
// this one outputs :  the new one:     Promise::304 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

WebdriverJS is purely asynchronous. Meaning, you need to provide a callback and instantiate your variable inside the callback rather than simply assigning the call the results of the function to your variable.

That's why you will always get a promise everytime you console.log your access_token variable. The webdriverjs docs explain a little about how promises work in selenium-webdriver https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Understanding_the_API

You can do the following to assign the text to a variable:

```
var access_token;    

var promise = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("AccToken")).getText();

promise.then(function(text) {
    access_token = text;
});
```

I highly recommend WebdriverIO as it takes away from the pain of having to write your own promises. http://webdriver.io/

Answer (score 3):

So this is one thing that I have had to learn the hard way, so I hope this helps:

```
var access_token = await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("AccToken"))
    .getAttribute("value")
    .then((value) => { return value; });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Webdriver you are using, but you may have some luck using WebdriverIO. Specifically its getText() function which will return a callback with the text so you can use it elsewhere.

http://webdriver.io/api/property/getText.html

```
client.getText('#elem').then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine if you are looking to just get the value. If you are using the new await ES6 syntax no need to "then" the promise.

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const assert = require('assert');
    
let access_token = await driver.findElement(By.name("AccToken")).getAttribute("value");
```

Then you can even just assert:

```
assert.equal(access_token, "your token value here");
```

More information can be found at the documentation for [selenium-webdriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html). Take a look at the Webdriver instance methods for a closer look. Good luck!